# What AWS linux configuration require for load testing of 20k-50k users

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

We are going to purchase AWS linux box to setup jmeter and do load testing from this server.

We will be sending 20k to 50k requests in minimum minutes so to achieve this what kind of configuration we require. i,e Ram, bandwidth, hard disk etc.

Remember one thing , this is server from where we will be sending requests via jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way to find out. Test it. It is test-steps depended, not just the number of requests.

Setup a single instance on Amazon, do a load test and ramp-up requests until you hit the limit of the single box. Let's take a guess and say 1000k requests per second per box. (Do measure this)

Divide the 20-50k by the max number of requests = total machines.

Example: 50.000 \ 1.000 = 50 machines.

I don't think you can do this from a single instance. I would probably buy lots of small instances and [cluster them](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html). Linux technically accepts 64k connections on a single machine, but io and memory will probably be the bottle-neck.

Should be relative easy to measure how a machine behaves while running your tests:

- Measure CPU
- IO
- RAM usage

And multiply by the number of wanted requests.

Comment: When you say **single box** it means single instance, correct?

Comment: @HelpingHands yes :) let me edit that